# Design Changes in Xamarin.Forms causes events to fail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

If I create a new cross platform app and add a button to the default layout and add a click event then all behaves as expected.  If I change the layout and place any other elements into the app then the events fail to fire. I am testing against a connected device but have also tried this on an emulator.

This works:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button x:Name="Testbtn" Text="Click Me" />
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Testbtn.Clicked += OnClicked;     
}

async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    await DisplayAlert("Test", String.Format("Clicked !! {0}", btn.Text), "OK");
}
```

When the layout is changed the app re-builds but the events do not fire...

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3.333" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3.333" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3.333" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" >             
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Text="Click Me" />
        <Button x:Name="btnTest1" Text="And Another" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Testbtn.Clicked += OnClicked; 
    Testbtn1.Clicked += OnClicked;      
}

async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    await DisplayAlert("Test", String.Format("Clicked !! {0}", btn.Text), "OK");
}
```

Comment: You can close your VS, then open your project, to delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders, then rebuild your project, if this issue is still existed , you can upload your demo to github.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are named differently in XAML than what you refer to in the code behind. What you have is:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Text="Click Me" />
<Button x:Name="btnTest1" Text="And Another" />
```

so the code behind should be:

```
btnTest.Clicked += OnClicked; 
btnTest1.Clicked += OnClicked;
```

instead of:

```
Testbtn.Clicked += OnClicked; 
Testbtn1.Clicked += OnClicked;
```

Comment: Hi Sorry about that I just knocked the example up! The principle remains the buttons whatever they are called fail to fire when the original template is altered!

Comment: Does it work if you add the Clicked property in the XAML like this: `<Button x:Name="btnTest1" Text="And Another" Clicked="OnClicked" />`?

Comment: Yes tried it from the XAML as well it works as long as the layout is not altered! I am wondering if the install either the sdk or the templates have been corupted on install and I need to clear the whole install for my laptop and start again?

Comment: That sounds very unlikely. I would try to clean the solution and do a new build or just rebuild it. Additionally, it might make sense to just restart Visual Studio or your whole machine. Sometimes VS acts up and a restart fixes the issue.